# Does haskell hide types if the same name is used in a different module?

Tags: haskell

**EDIT**

All thee answers did explain it well enough, just one final thing, can anyone point me to the documentation about the types, so I can understand how the types are handled internally

I am trying to implement a wrapper type for IO, to understand types. I have created a IO' type which is actually using the IO to construct.

```
data IO' a = IO a

test :: String -> IO' String
test x = IO x 

convert :: IO' String -> String
convert (IO x) =  x

main = do
        a <- getLine
        return $ convert.test $ a
```

However now if I try to use IO to return an IO action then it fails, example the following function fails giving the expected vs actual type error:

```
fail :: IO String
fail = IO "test"
```

So in Haskell are types using same names get hidden? Also how do I understand whether I am using data constructor or type constructor when I call IO.

Finally, seems like a silly question but I tried to find the documentation for System.IO and later for List type as well, and am not able to find it.

Comment: I'm not much above beginner at Haskell myself, so I don't offer this as an answer - but my understanding is that there is no constructor function in the standard libraries called `IO` - so `IO "test"` only makes sense in your code because you've defined `IO` as a constructor of your `IO'` type. So your definition of `fail` is going to cause a type error. (Expects IO String but actually gets IO' String.) It seems to be that all Haskell's IO functions are constructed by "magic" behind the scenes (well, in C, I suspect), you can't implement them in pure Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to implement a wrapper type for IO,

You did not though. There's no reference to the `IO` type anywhere in your data declaration.

> ```
> data IO' a = IO a
> ```

That `IO` on the right-hand side is not the type `IO`. It's not even a type. That is just the name you chose for the value constructor of your data type `IO'`.

If you ask ghc the type of `IO` you'll get,

```
> :t IO
IO :: a -> IO' a
```

You could have chosen any other name for it, e.g.

> ```
> data IO' a = C a
> ```

It's just a constructor for values of type `IO'`

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is hidden in your code.

In Haskell, the type- and value-languages are strictly separated. Broadly speaking, everything to the right of a `::` or `data`/`newtype`/`type` keyword (except the name-declaration for value constructors) lives in the type-level language, everything else lives in the value-level language.

```
     ┌─────┐   ┌──┐        ┌─┐
data │IO' a│ = │IO│        │a│
     └─────┤   └value-level└┬┘
           └─type-level─────┘

        ┌───────────┐
fail :: │ IO String │
        └──────────type-level
┌────────────────┐
fail = IO "test" │
└───────────────value-level
```

The type-level `IO` is unambiguously `Prelude.IO` (because you named your type `IO'` instead), whereas the value-level `IO` is unambiguously the data constructor to `IO'` that you defined yourself (because `Prelude.IO` does not export any constructors called either `IO` or otherwise).

Hiding would only become relevant if you actually used the same name `IO` again for the *type constructor*:

```
import Prelude hiding (IO)

data IO a = IO a

test :: String -> IO String
test x = IO x 

convert :: IO String -> String
convert (IO x) =  x

fail' :: IO String
fail' = IO "test"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're defining two things: A type named `IO'` and a constructor named `IO`. Neither of them hide anything because the standard library defines neither a type named `IO'` (only `IO`) nor a constructor named `IO` (the standard `IO` type doesn't have any constructors). So since constructors and types live in different name spaces (meaning you can have a constructor and a type with the same name without any problems), nothing is being hidden.

So with your definitions, you now have the types `IO` (referring to `Prelude.IO`) and `IO'` (referring to your type) and the constructor `IO :: a -> IO' a`.

Your definition of `fail` does not work because `IO` constructs a value of type `IO'`, not `IO`. There is no connection between your `IO` constructor and the `IO` type, so there is no reason this should work.